# Добавление пользовательских полей в MiniShop2

Tags: modx, minishop2

Добрый день! У меня такой вопрос: как можно расширить функционал товаров плагина MiniShop. Дело в том, что стандартный набор полей меня не устраивает, хотелось бы внести свои поля в интернет-магазин. Пробовал создавать пользовательские поля и привязывать их к товарам, но в чанке обращения к ним не дало никакого результата. Писал разными способами: [[+tv.namefield]], [[*namefield]]? [[!+namefield]], и все без толку… Нашел статью, которая рассказывает, что надо переписывать логику снипетов miniShop2 https://bezumkin.ru/modx/minishop2/classes/910/, однако тут тоже возникла трудность - таких директорий (какие указаны в статье) я просто не нашел. Подскажите, кто работал уже с этим. Хотелось бы решить задачу как можно быстрее…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение такой проблемы в следующем, прописываем TV-переменные и префикс:

```
[[!msProducts?
    &includeTVs=`field1,field2`
    &tvPrefix=`tv.`
]]
```

А в чанке вызываем поля таким образом:

```
[[+tv.field1]] и [[+tv.field2]]
```

Пишу для тех, кому может пригодится это.

Comment: TV поля Безумкин не рекомендует для минишопа! Так как они в своей таблице, а почти весь минишоп крутится внутри своего набора таблиц! есть же опции, чем не подошли???